# Where are standard streams stdin and stdout created?

Tags: c, stdout, stdin

In ANSI C, we say input is taken by (s/v/f)scanf and stored in `stdin`, we say something for `stdout` when talking about output. However I wonder where they reside in Linux (Unix). Do they reside under a specific folder? Or are they (`stdin`/`stdout`) arbitrary (that is, no such things exist)?

Comment: Why? What do you want to do with the folder they reside in?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can access any process' file descriptor via `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fd_number>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stdin` is a `FILE *` referring to the stdio (standard io) structure that is tied to the file descriptor `0`.  File descriptors are what Unix-like systems, such as Linux, use to talk with applications about particular file-like things.  (Actually, I'm pretty sure that Windows does this as well).

File descriptor `0` may refer to any type of *file*, but to make sense it must be one that `read` can be called on (it must be a regular file, a steam socket, or a character device opened for reading or the read side of a pipe, as opposed to a directory file, data gram socket, or a block device).

Processes in Unix-like systems inherit their open file descriptors from their parent process in Unix-like systems.  So to run a program with stdin set to something besides the parent's stdin you would do:

```
 int new_stdin = open("new_stdin_file, O_RDONLY);
 pid_t fk = fork();
 if (!fk) { // in the child
     dup2(new_stdin, 0);
     close(new_stdin);
     execl("program_name", "program_name", NULL);
     _exit(127); // should not have gotten here, and calling exit (without _ ) can have
                 // side effects because it runs atexit registered functions, and we
                 // don't want that here
 } else if (fk < 0) {
      // in parent with error from fork
 } else {
     // in parent with no error so fk = pid of child
 }
 close(new_stdin); // we don't need this anymore
```

`dup2` duplicates the first file descriptor argument as the second (closing the second before doing so if it were open for the current process).

`fork` creates a duplicate of the current process.  `execl` is one of the `exec` family of functions, which use the `execve` system call to replace the current program with another program.  The combination of `fork` and `exec` are how programs are generally run (even when hidden within other functions).

In the above example we could have run the new program with stdin set to the read end of a pipe, a tty (serial port / TeleTYpe), or several other things.  Some of these have names present in the filesystem and others do not (like some pipes and sockets, though some do have names in the filesystem).

Linux makes `/proc/self/fd/0` a symbolic link to the file opened as `0` in the current process.  `/proc/%i/fd/0`, `pid` would represent the symbolic link to the same thing for an arbitrary pid (process ID) using the `printf` syntax.  These symbolic links are often usable to find the real file in the filesystem (using the readlink system call), but if the file does not actually exist in the filesystem the link data (what would usually be a file name) instead is just a string that tells a little bit about the file.

I should point out here that a file that stdin (fd 0) refers to, even if it is in the filesystem, may not have just one name.  It may have more than one hard link, so it would have more than one name -- and each of these would be just as much its name as any other hard link.  Additionally it may have no name at all if all of its hard links have been `unlinked` since it was opened, though it's data would still live on the disk until all open file descriptors for it are closed.

If you don't actually need to know where it is in the filesystem, but just want some data about it you can use the `fstat` system call.  This is like the `stat` system call and command line utility, except for already open files.

Everything I said here about `stdin` (fd 0) should be applicable to stdout (fd 1) and stderr (fd 2) except that they will both be writable rather than readable.

If you want to know more about any of the functions I mentioned be sure to look them up in the man pages by typing:

```
man fork
```

on the command line.  Most functions I mentioned are in section 2 of the man pages, but one or two may be in section one, so `man 2 fork` will work too, and may be useful when a command line tool has the same name as a function.

Answer (score 7):

They are streams created for your process by the operating system. There is no named file object associated with them, and so they do not have a representation within the file system, although as unwind points out, they may be accessed via a pseudo file system if your UNIX variant supports such a thing.

Comment: I've been away from SO for a bit - good to see that clueless downvoters are still here in abundance.

Comment: +1 because a clear and a precise answer to an unclear question

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, you can generally find `stdin` through the [/proc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) file system in `/proc/self/fd/0`, and stdout is `/proc/self/fd/1`.

Answer (score 1):

`stdin` is standard input - for example, keyboard input.
`stdout` is standard output - for example, monitor.

For more info, read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

Comment: I know, please delete your advise

Comment: @gcc: dheerosaur has answered you question as it was asked. If this answer is not what you are looking for then you need to clarify your question. @dheerosaur, +1 from me mate.

Comment: @unwind gives the required answer

Comment: @Binary Worrier, Thanks mate, I remember answering a question that was titled differently. Can OPs change the question title in SO?

Comment: @dheerosaur: Yes, the asker - or anyone with enough rep for that matter - can change the title or content of a question.

Comment: @gcc: "I know, please delete your advice", sorry I just put my finger on what else was bothering me about that statement (other than it is rude, and that there is nothing wrong with this answer). You may already know this, but others - who may find your question through an SO or google search - may not know this. It's useful information and pertinent to the question you asked. This answer stands and should not be deleted.

Comment: @gcc: If you liked the answer from @unwind then you should have picked it as the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you run:

```
./myprog < /etc/passwd
```

then `stdin` exists in the filesystem as `/etc/passwd`. If you just run

```
./myprog
```

interactively on a terminal, then `stdin` exists in the filesystem as whatever your terminal device is (probably `/dev/pts/5` or something).

If you run

```
cat /etc/passwd | ./myprog
```

then `stdin` is an anonymous pipe and has no instantiation in the filesystem, but Linux allows you to get at it via `/proc/12345/fd/0` where `12345` is the pid of `myprog`.